# C++ Library API Design issues

Tags: c++, api, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am creating a C++ library for use by third parties. While I am familiar with creating C libraries I have little experience creating C++ libraries. My concern is that there are additional issues presented by C++ library APIs which I need to consider. Such as :

1. Exception handling across the API.
2. User access of class members for objects created by the library
3. User destruction of objects created by the library and vice versa.
4. Who knows what else ...

What must I consider above and beyond that which I must consider for C libraries?

Best Regards

Comment: 1. I'll let others answer this question
2. just no `public` members at all, always use seters/getters if user need to access some class members
3. try to avoid forcing user or your library to delete objects he/it didn't created

Comment: You must consider all these and much more co-Padawan! Exception handling is obviously an extremely important point. Prior to this, you must consider whether all your clients will infact be C++ aware, or you might have to consider catching exceptions at boundaries and returning C type success/failures instead. Memory management considerations are paramount as well - not ensuring contained memory management can land you in a big soup of mismatching allocation and deallocation heaps by clients. So, while there's not much I can add as an answer, I don't also think there's such a comprehensive list

Comment: If you target Windows, your customers *must* use the exact same compiler version you do. This is less of a problem on Linux and Mac OS X. IME on Windows C++ APIs are not worth the effort. The library may be written in C++ but export only C-compatible APIs.

Answer (score 6):

C++ is a more complex language than C, so there are a lot more issues that you need to be aware of. There are always language neutral concerns like how to design a good public/private separation, documentation, versioning, maintaining backward compatibility, etc. But there also various C++-specific issues, such as const correctness, your use of templates, exceptions vs return codes, not exposing data members, your use of inheritance, considering copy constructors and assignment operators, use of pointers or references, default arguments, friends, use of inline, etc.

In full disclosure, I am the author of the book "API Design for C++". Without wanting to sound like I'm pushing the book, it does cover exactly the topic that you're asking about: how to design good APIs for C++. You can view the table of contents of the book to give you a good overview of the issues you should be considering. Also, the sample chapter includes a discussion of the pimpl idiom, which I personally like as a way to provide better encapsulation in C++.

http://www.apibook.com/blog/contents

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft do provide design guidelines for class libraries, not sure if such exists for Linux as well, but these are general guidelines and should apply to various platforms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(v=vs.71).aspx